# How to efficiently increment a value in an alphabet

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm

Say you have an alphabet that has these characters in this order:

```
abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFG123456789
```

You want to then increment them to an arbitrary length. So it starts off with just 1 character, then 2, then 3, then ... n.

```
a
b
c
...
A
B
C
...
1
2
3
...
aa
ab
...
aA
aB
...
ba
bb
bc
...
bA
bB
...
za
zb
...
1a
1b
...
aaa
aab
aac
...
aba
abb
abc
...
aAa
aAb
...
```

So it increments the right-most first, then the next to the left, then left of that, etc.

It is kind of tricky. Wondering how to do this.

Wondering how to do it such that it can take **any** alphabet, and construct it up to any length, so it's generic.

```
function getStringAtIndex(index, alphabetArray) {

}
```

Or perhaps it can be done in a different way, I'm not sure.

Comment: Sounds like you are wanting to represent a number in an arbitrary base. When `n` is less than the number of characters in your alphabet, you have one digit. Then while `n` is less than `N*N`, you have two digits. Etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@tehhowch is exactly right, instead of doing hex (base 16), you're essentially wanting to do base-n math. With the character set you specified, this would be base-33 math (if you include the 0 character)

Every decimal place represents n^x power. It's easy with decimal. 100 is 10^2, and 1000 is 10^3. And that's what a logarithm is: log(1000) base 10 = 3, because 10^3 = 1000.

Fortunately we can get a log of any base by doing log(n)/log(base). Hence the following function:

```
function convert(number) {
    var chars = '0abcdefghijklmnopABCDEFG123456789',
        base = chars.length, i = number, str = '',
        exp = Math.floor(Math.log(i)/Math.log(base))+1;
    while(exp--) {
        var bexp = Math.pow(base, exp);
        var j = Math.floor(i/bexp);
        i -= j*bexp;
        str += chars[j];
    }
    return str;
}
convert(90014234); // "bi62Gb"
convert(791424) // "F01B"
convert(23423); // "Ep3"
convert(33); // "a0"
```

You can verify the method by using a more common character set, like hexadecimal (base 16), and making sure the numbers come out right. You'd substitute `var chars = '0123456789abcdef'` in the function. Then we specify a hex number and make sure our output matches:

```
convert(0xdd5439af); // "dd5439af"
```